# Can I execute a p:remoteCommand before p:XX rendered="#{class.func} is evaluated?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a remoteCommand which toggles a boolean in my backend bean, and I would like to use this boolean to determine whether a Primefaces component should be rendered or not.

The problem is that my remoteCommand is executed after the rendered attribute is evaluated on each component.

Q: Is there a way to get an information from the client side, transfer it to the backend bean and based on some logic there determine whether a component should be rendered or not?

Additional information: To get the client side information I need to execute a javascript function.

Comment: Can't you just let the remote command `update` the target components?

Comment: That does work, but the loading time of the page is very long and the user can see the sudden re-rendering of the page.

Comment: Then always hide it on initial page load and show some loading indicator in place of it?

Comment: or create an initial landing page that just does the 'detection' and calling the `remoteCommand`. Store the result server side in a session and use it in other pages.